# Two NSArrayControllers bound to same NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: swift, objective-c, core-data, cascading-deletes, nsarraycontroller

I have two nib files each with its own window populated by data from the same Core Data Managed Object Context (MOC) but each bound to a different array-controller. The problem is that when I delete a data object in one of the window's array-controller, it persists in the other window's array-controller even after saving the common MOC and restarting the program. To permanently remove the unwanted data object, I must remove it at each window separately. This doesn't seem the way Core Data should work. Shouldn't array controllers using the same MOC have a common source of persistent data?

Comment: Yes, array controllers using the same MOC and entity contain the same data (if `fetchPredicate` and `filterPredicate` are `nil`). Post a [mre] please.

Comment: Thank you Willeke for confirming my hypothesis that NSArrayControllers bound to a common MOC should reflect the data of that common MOC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my setup of the bound array-controller, it is not enough to simply connect the window's 'delete' button to NSControllerArray's 'remove:' method. Instead, I subclass this method and specify a direct MOC delete of the target data-object as follows:

```
- (void)remove:(id)sender
{ 
    [MOC deleteObject:[[self selectedObjects] lastObject]];
}
```